# $G$ with an operation is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help to answer the folowing problem:

> Let $F$ be a field, $n\ge 1$ and $G=F^n\bigoplus F^n\bigoplus Mat(n,F).$ That is an element of $G$ has the form $(v,w,X)$ where $v$ and $w$ are n-by-1 vectors and $X$ is $n$-by$-n$ matrix, all with entires in $F$.
>
> Define an operator on $G$ by:
>
> $$(v_1,w_1,X_1)(v_2,w_2,X_2)=(v_1+v_2,w_1+w_2,X_1+X_2+v_1w_2^t)$$
>
> Show that $G$ with this operation is a group.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this not just a simple matter of proving the associativity formula, identifying the identity, and determining inverses?

Comment: Those look ***different***. Anyway, what do you mean by $v_1w_2$ anyway?

Comment: i edit i forgot the transpose

Comment: For associativity i wrote                                                     
        $[(v_1,w_1,X_1)(v_2,w_2,X_2)](v_3,w_3,X_3)=(v_1+v_2,w_1+w_2,X_1+X_2+v_1w_2^t)(v_3,w_3,X_3)=(v_1+v_2+v_3,w_1+w_2+w_3,X_1+X_2++v_1w_2^t+X_3+(v_1+v_2)w_3^t)$ and   $(v_1,w_1,X_1)[(v_2,w_2,X_2)(v_3,w_3,X_3)]=(v_1,w_1,X_1)(v_2+v_3,w_2+w_3,X_2+X_3+v_2w_3^t)=(v_1+v_2+v_3,w_1+w_2+w_3,X_2+X_3+v_2w_3^t +X_1+v_1(w_2+w_3)^t)$

Comment: @mona Please don't answer the question one comment at a time. You can edit your calculations into the question and ask if they are right, or edit the question to say that you can do part of the proof but are stuck at [provide details].

Comment: what is the identity here?

Comment: As given from the operation you defined, $(0,0,0)$ works fine (?)

Comment: and what is the inverse?

Comment: You can solve it from the given relations. $v_2=-v_1$, $w_2=-w_1$, $X_2 = -X_1 - v_1w_2^t= -X_1+v_1w_1^t .$

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that $(v_0,w_0,X_0)$ is the identity. We need to have 
$$
(v,w,X)(v_0,w_0,X_0)=(v,w,X)
$$
for any $v,w,X$. If you look at the first coordinate, you need $v+v_0=v$, so $v_0=0$. Looking at the second coordinate, $w+w_0=w$, so $w_0=0$. The equality between third coordinates now became
$$
X+X_0+vw_0^t=X.
$$
But we already know that $w_0=0$, so for this to hold for all $X$ we need $X_0=0$. So the neutral element is $(0,0,0)$ (where, of course, the first two zeroes are the one from $\mathbb F^n$, and the third one the one from $\text{Mat}\,(n,\mathbb F)$.

You can try to find the inverse using the same idea.

Comment: Let $(v,w,X)$ in the groupe. Let us assume that $(v_0,w_0,X_0)$ is the inverse. We need to have 
$$
(v,w,X)(v_0,w_0,X_0)=(0,0,0)
$$
 If you look at the first coordinate, you need $v+v_0=0$, so $v_0=-v$. Looking at the second coordinate, $w+w_0=0$, so $w_0=-w$. The equality between third coordinates now became
$$
X+X_0-vw^t=0.
$$
 so $X_0=-X+vw$. Is that right?

Comment: And how we show that $G'=\left\{(0,0,X), X\in Mat(n,F)\right\}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't know what you mean by $G'$.

Comment: $G'$ is the derived groupe of $G$ i.e $G'=\left\{ [a,b], a,b\in G\right\}$

Comment: Note that the group is abelian in its first two components.

Comment: i didn't understand what you said, can you please explain more with details . Thanks